# Blueprint CSS centering in grid

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Just started using Blueprint CSS and now playing with the grids but have a simple problem.  I created a navbar at the top of my page with each link 2 columns wide (using span-2).  What is the right way to center these links inside the grid columns without hacking away at the css.

```
<div id="navbar" class="container showgrid">  
    <div class="span-2 border">  
        <a href="news" class="caps">News</a>  
    </div>  
    <div class="span-2 border">  
        <a href="gigs" class="caps">Gigs</a>  
    </div>  
    <div class="span-2 border">  
        <a href="tunes" class="caps">Tunes</a>  
    </div>  
    <div class="span-2 border">  
        <a href="mailing-list" class="caps">Email&nbsp;List</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a helper class like this:

css:

```
.text-center{ text-align:center; }
```

html:

```
<div class="span-2 border text-center">  
    <a href="news" class="caps">News</a>  
</div>  
<div class="span-2 border text-center">  
    <a href="gigs" class="caps">Gigs</a>  
</div>
```